# Access any site's service worker context/world/excution environment to proxy self.registration.showNotification via browser addon?

Tags: javascript, notifications, service-worker, firefox-addon-webextensions, proxy-pattern

I'd like to create a browser extension that at its core proxies the `registration.showNotification` function to filter then based on rules set within the addon. Proxying `window.Notification` is trivial, but I'm having trouble even approaching the problem. I know I can get service worker registrations, but reassigning `showNotification` doesn't seem to be permanent and doesn't actually seem to work except when I'm the one calling the function through the console.

My 'last resort' idea (which seems difficult) is intercept and modify incoming requests to modify the `showNotification` function via `window.postMessage` or something similar - but I want that to be the last resort.

Is there any conceivable way to do what I'm trying to do here? Or maybe a API I'm missing? Based on my research so far my guess is no. I'm not the most experienced when in comes to JS, so I thought I'd give this question a shot. I'm using Firefox if that makes a difference.

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using? `showNotification` does not work before FF78

Answer (score -1):

On the Firefox Addons Store there is a similar extension, [Service Worker Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/service-worker-control/), and you can find its source [here](https://github.com/jingyu9575/service-worker-control), under the MPL license.

Now, more specifically, I understand you want to intercept or change the `showNotification` function, which can be achieved by something similar to the code below (a [snippet](https://github.com/jingyu9575/service-worker-control/blob/master/preload.js) adapted from the above cited source):

```js
const showNotification_backup = ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype.showNotification

function showNotification(title, options) {
    const obj = { type: 'notification', isInjected }
    try {
        const sw = this.installing || this.waiting || this.active
        obj.url = typeof sw === 'object' && sw ? '' + sw.scriptURL : undefined
    } catch { }
    try { obj.scope = '' + this.scope } catch { }
    try { obj.title = '' + title } catch { }
    try { obj.body = '' + options.body } catch { }
    send(obj)
    return showNotification_backup.apply(this, arguments)
}

if (setupCondition) {
    ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype.showNotification = showNotification
} else {
    exportFunction(showNotification, ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype,
            { defineAs: 'showNotification' })
}
```

where `exportFunction` is part of [XPCOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction), thus changing the prototype of the ServiceWorker.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, `XPCOM` is outdated and almost completely deprecated, leaving you with only modifying the prototype of the service worker registrations, as below:

```js
let registrations = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()

if (registrations.length > 0) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(registrations[0]).showNotification = showNotification
}
```

This indeed directly modifies the prototype chain method, which is not a good JS practice, however considering the given `showNotification` function applies the arguments to the original one, it somewhat *extends* it.

Comment: "XPCOM is no longer available for use by Firefox extensions. Use WebExtensions instead." How unfortunate!